# fadeIn() element with opacity:0

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why `fadeIn()` function doesn't perform the show animation for the element which already has `opacity:0`?

```
<span style="display:none;opacity:0">some text</span>

<script>
    $("span").fadeIn(3000) /* id doesn't show the element. JQuery function just removes display:none, but opacity is still 0 */
</script>
```

I know, I can call `fadeTo()` but I want to know what is going on.

Comment: @dev-null those answers don't solve the problem. They say fadeIn() shows only hidden elements, but my element is hidden (display:none), it just has addition opacity:0, that's all.

Comment: `fadeIn()` only does the transition of element by setting the opacity from 0 to 100 by itself. It doesn't touch the existing css properties and thus would not convert the opacity automatically.

Comment: It seems I know the answer. First fadeIn() resets opacity to 0 and then increase it to the previous value - in my case it's 0 again. So opacity even doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to show the element before

```
$("span").show().fadeIn(3000);
```

Comment: it just removes display:none, but opacity is still not animated by fadeIn()